# Anti-refresh (F5) submit form in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, page-refresh

How to prevent refresh form page in CodeIgniter?

If I use redirect — all fine, but I can directly appeal to page site.com/update/success.
How can I prevent direct access to success page (only from site.com/update/) ?

Controller update.php

```
public function index() {
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      $data['error'] = 'Something wrong';
      $this->load->view('update', $data);
   } else {
      redirect('/update/success');
   }
}

public function success() {
   $message = 'Your profile has been successfully updated';
   $this->load->view($message);
}
```

Comment: one does not simply disable refresh . .

Comment: session flash data and a script on page load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a token in flashdata in your index() function and then check for that token in your success() method.

```
class Update extends CI_Controller {

    property $token;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index() {
       if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
          $data['error'] = 'Something wrong';
          $this->load->view('update', $data);
       } else {
          $this->session->set_flashdata('update_token', time());
          redirect('/update/success');
       }
    }

    public function success() {

        // Make sure this request came from the index() method...
        if( ! $this->session->flashdata('update_token'))
        {
            redirect();
        }

       $message = 'Your profile has been successfully updated';
       $this->load->view($message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a time ago i used codeigniter so im not sure.

maybe you can make the succes function private and just call it in the else like this:

```
    public function index() {
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data['error'] = 'Something wrong';
            $this->load->view('update', $data);
        } else {
            $this->success();
        }
   }



    private function success() {
       $message = 'Your profile has been successfully updated';
       $this->load->view($message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index() {
   if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
      $data['error'] = 'Something wrong';
      $this->load->view('update', $data);
   } else {
      // create success session/cookie
      $this->_success()
   }
}

public function _success() {
   // destroy success session when called
    // checks success session if existing if not the page has been refreshed redirect
   $message = 'Your profile has been successfully updated';
   echo $this->nocache();
   $this->load->view($message);
}

public function _nocache()
{
 header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
 header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
 header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
```

YOu can add '_' underscore so that it is not accessible by url, and add a no cache  to the headers so that the page will not stay cache on the browser when they click back or access the same url again.

*code not tested*

Comment: You can use $this->output->set_header() instead of php native header function also if you want to protect your method being accessed via url use private modifier.

Comment: @ShayanHusaini, nope i prefer the native function as CI's set header tends to be crack sometimes, and adding an _ underscore even when the method is public makes the method unaccessible via url, but yes setting it to private is also an option